# How to access the texture of the default framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

When i create my own framebuffer this is the process

```
glGenerateBuffers() // generate a buffer
glCreateTextures()  // create a texture
bind the texture to the buffer
once we have rendered in the framebuffer we can use the texture.
```

Do we have a texture available for the default framebuffer and can we access it ?

Comment: `glGenerateBuffers` That is not an OpenGL function. You might have meant `glGenBuffers`, but those generate buffer objects, which have nothing to do with framebuffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffers used by the [default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) are defined at context creation time, and are owned by whatever mechanism was responsible for creating the context that the default framebuffer refers to. You cannot access them in any way other than as parts of the default framebuffer (unless the context creation mechanism itself provides you with a way to do so).

Comment: if i want to attach a PBO to the default OpenGL framebuffer  is that possible or i need to create my own framebufffer and attach the PBO to the texture of the buffer.

Comment: @sam: A PBO is a buffer object. With the exception of buffer textures, you don't attach buffer objects of any kind to textures. And certainly not to framebuffers. Of any kind. But in any case, you cannot attach anything to a default framebuffer. As stated in this answer, the buffers used by the default framebuffer are defined and owned by the context, not by you.